# Finding yearly weather statistics from tomorrow's weather probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to solve this problem from a book, but so far I haven't found how to approach it...

[image: Here is the problem]

I made a graph, and tried to calculate some probabilities..  but nothing

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like the weather is assumed to follow a Markov chain. Do you know any theory behind markov chains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a Markov chain with a given transition matrix. This matrix is the transpose of your table. The task is to find an eigenvector of the matrix for the eigenvalue $1$ and normalize it w.r.t. the $\|\cdot\|_1$-Norm (i.e. make sure all components sum to $1$; they will all be nonnegative)

$$M = \pmatrix{.4&.2&.25&.1\\.4&.2&.25&.4\\.2&.3&.25&.2\\0&.3&.25&.3}$$

Now solve $Mp = p$ where $p\in [0,1]^4$ and $\|p\|_1 = 1$. The resulting $p$ will then contain the probabilities in order of the weather conditions Sunny, Cloudy, Windy and Rainy.

This $p$ is also called "stationary distribution".

Comment: Justt a note to the OP: this normalized eigenvector is sometimes referred to as the "stationary" distribution.

Comment: @5xum Thanks, I added that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations! :) I didn't know what was a Markov chain. I will look for more info on the web and will try to solve this problem.

Comment: @WilliamGéraldBlondel Happy to help ;)

Comment: @WilliamGéraldBlondel If you multiply $p$ from the left as a row vector, you must use the transpose of my matrix. Also it's unwise to chose $p$ as a name for one of its components. $p = \pmatrix{p_{\text{sunny}}\\p_{\text{cloudy}}\\p_{\text{windy}}\\p_{\text{rainy}}}$ might be a better naming.

Comment: I don't know if I solved it the same way you told me, but I think I found the solution. I had to calculate p=(p q r s) such as p=pM.
So I had
$$
pM = \left ( p\: q\: r\: s \right )\left \begin{pmatrix}
0,4 & 0,2 & 0,25 & 0,1 \\ 
0,4 & 0,2 & 0,25 & 0,4 \\ 
0,2 & 0,3 & 0,25 & 0,2 \\ 
0 & 0,3 & 0,25 & 0,3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so
$$
pM = \begin{pmatrix}
0,4p+0,4q+0,2r & 0,2p+0,2q+0,3r+0,3s & 0,25p+0,25q+0,25r+0,25s & 0,1p+0,4q+0,2r+0,3s
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I transformed that into a system of equation with 4 variables that I solved with Gauss–Seidel method. 
I found p = (1/4 1/4 1/4 1/4). Is that correct?

Comment: @WilliamGéraldBlondel No. See my previous comment. $Mp = \pmatrix{.4 p_1 + .2 p_2 + .25 p_3 + .1 p_4 \\ .4 p_1 + \ldots \\ \vdots}$

Comment: Yes I just saw it, sorry, I had trouble making the Latex formatting work.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm stuck I don't find any solutions :( I think I don't know the technique to solve that

Comment: Take a look at [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) on the topic to see if it can help you.